# QuantLib: How to bootstrap Yield Curve using 3M futures - Python

Tags: quantlib, finance-mathematics, yield-curve, bootstrapping, interpolation

I need to bootstrap a yieldcurve with 3M futures, using a cubic spline if possible.

Using, for example 3M Euribor, how do I bootstrap the yield curve using python?

I have a vector of dates and a vector of future prices.

I found about the QuantLib library, and more specifically, the `ql.PiecewiseCubicZero`. However there is a big lack of documentation on how to use it, and even more, with futures.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The theory and a worked-out example are in [Ametrano and Bianchetti, *Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Multiple Interest Rate Curve Bootstrapping but Were Afraid to Ask*](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2219548).

Recently I reproduced their example in Python; you can read my code at https://www.implementingquantlib.com/2023/09/ametrano-bianchetti.html.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a really easy answer, you can do the following:

1. Convert your futures prices into rates e.g. $100 - price = rate$.
2. Construct a `LineCurve` in `rateslib`:

```python
from rateslib import *
curve = LineCurve(
    nodes={
        dt(2023, 9, 21): 3.92,
        dt(2023, 12, 20): 4.01,
        dt(2024, 3, 20): 3.96,
        dt(2024, 6, 20): 3.83,
        dt(2024, 9, 20): 3.62,
        dt(2024, 12, 20): 3.42,
        dt(2025, 3, 20): 3.25,
    },
    t=[
        dt(2023, 9, 21), dt(2023, 9, 21), dt(2023, 9, 21), dt(2023, 9, 21),
        dt(2023, 12, 20),
        dt(2024, 3, 20),
        dt(2024, 6, 20),
        dt(2024, 9, 20),
        dt(2024, 12, 20),
        dt(2025, 3, 20), dt(2025, 3, 20), dt(2025, 3, 20), dt(2025, 3, 20),
    ]
)
curve.plot()
```

[image]

The `t` parameter is the **knot sequence** which is needed to instruct a cubic spline. You can read about this in the [rateslib docs](https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

The `curve` rate on 18th Jan 2024

```python
>>> curve[dt(2024, 1, 18)]
4.008222134667067
```

The curve that is produced is a futures curves and it ignores convexity adjustments which are generally created by the presence of a swaps market.